# Unity plays only a few gameobject's sound

Tags: audio, unity-game-engine, 2d, unity3d-2dtools

I'm developing a 2D game, and have a Button prefab what plays a sound when clicked.

I have multiple instance of this prefab on my scene, but only 2 of them plays the sound, the others don't play anything, or just a very short something.

I thought that it is caused by the distance of the camera and the gameObject, but if I place a button what is silent, to the position of a working button, it still won't play anything.

My code is simple:

```
...
public AudioSource myAudioSrc;

public AudioClip btnSound;
...
protected virtual void OnMouseUpAsButton() {
    if(!isEnabled) { return; }
    myRenderer.sprite       = normalImg;
    transform.localScale    = normalSize;

    myAudioSrc.PlayOneShot(btnSound);
    Debug.Log(gameObject.name);

    //üzenet küldése az objektumnak a message metódus hívására az data paraméterrel
    target.SendMessage(message, data);
}
...
```

**EDIT**:

I've got this working with the code:

```
 AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(btnSnd, Camera.main.transform.position);
```

So it has to do something with the distances.

Is there any better solution?

Comment: if you want to play simultaneously you should have more than one audio source

Comment: Please don't use the unity tag for questions related to the game engine, just use "unity3d" tag instead.

Comment: I have AudioSource for each instance, and they are not playing simultenously.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I disabled the gameobject with the OnMousUpAsButton event, so that's why the sound stopped playing.